# How to deal with iomanips in custom output operators?

Tags: c++, iomanip

I just came across the problem of combining custom output operators with io-manipulators. Maybe my expectations are completely off, but if

```
std::cout << foo() << "\n";
```

prints

```
00
```

then I would expect

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << foo() << "!\n"
```

to print

```
00                   !
```

but given this implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct foo { int a,b; };
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const foo& f) {
    out << f.a << f.b;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << foo() << "\n";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) <<  foo() << "!";
}
```

what is printed on the screen is

```
00
0                   0!
```

I see basically two options: A) My expectations are just wrong. B) I use this implementation instead:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const foo& f) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << f.a << f.b;
    out << ss.str();
    return out;
}
```

However, this seems like quite some overhead considering that most of the time no io manipulators are used.

**What is the idiomatic way of treating io-manipulators "correctly" in custom output operators?**

Comment: My go to solution would be to stringify it like you did in `B`.  Since output is slow already you might not even notice the hit.

Comment: @NathanOliver hum... I remember long time ago I was wondering whether I should make it my habit to write a `foo::toString()` or overload the `ostream::<<`, now I am starting to think it is best to have both

Comment: That would be another approach.  Then if your less expensive `operator <<` breaks the formatting you can make the choice to call the more expensive `to_string`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I actually meant `<<` calling the `toString`, well, dont know, have to meditate over it ;)

Comment: @user463035818 Things like `set::left`, `std::setw()`, etc that set flags on `std::ostream` usually only apply to the *next* invocation of `operator<<` on that `std::ostream, and then they get reset afterwards. That is why you see the alignment only being applied to `f.a` and not to `f.b` when using `out << f.a << f.b;`. This is documented behavior. If you want to format multiple values in a particular way, you have to format them yourself first, and then send the final result to `out`, like you do with `out << ss.str();`

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah that the argument in favour of A) my expectations are wrong. I just thought that `std::cout << foo();` appears to be a single invocation of `operator<<` and was hoping to get formatting independent of implementation details of `operator<<(foo)`

Comment: "*I just thought that `std::cout << foo();` appears to be a single invocation of `operator<<`*" - only from the caller's perspective, but not from the target `ostream`'s perspective. "*was hoping to get formatting independent of implementation details of `operator<<(foo)`*" - nope, the implementation of `operator<<(foo)` needs to take the caller's active manipulators into consideration when writing *multiple* values to the target `ostream`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, i dont disagree with anything you say, i am just a bit surprised how much more effort it is to write a `operator<<` that considers manipulators than i naively thought. I mean it is the caller who sets the manipulators and if I implement something stupid (as eg in my lousy answer) then the caller wont get what they expect

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no easy answer. Your solution is idiomatic if you only need to handle `std::setw` and `std::left`, but, for other manipulations, you have to decide the behavior of your formatter.

Imagine, for example, if your struct had *floats* instead of ints:

```
struct foo { float a,b; };
```

Then, your user tries to do this:

```
const long double pi = std::acos(-1.L);
std::cout << std::setprecision(10) << foo{0.0f, pi} << "!\n"
```

This is when you have to decide: Do you want to honor the precision property of the output stream, or do you want to ignore it? Your current implementation would ignore it, since it does the actual conversion in another stream.

To honor the precision property, you would have to copy it:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const foo& f) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss.precision(out.precision());
    ss << f.a << f.b;
    out << ss.str();
    return out;
}
```

For your case of integers, you also have to consider if you will honor `std::setbase` or not.

The same reasoning will have to be applied for the other manipulators, such as `std::setfill`, for example.

Comment: uuh right, now I remember the downside of a `toString`... would like to downvote my own answer ;). Actually I was wondering if there is a way to find out what manipulators are "active" on a given stream

Comment: @user463035818 `std::ostream` has methods for that: `flags()`, `precision()`, `width()`, `fill()`, etc.  You have to read them individually as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily idiomatic, but one possible appraoch is this:

```
struct foo { 
    int a,b;
    std::string toString() {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << a << b;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const foo& f) {
    out << a << b;
    return out;
};
```

Now the caller may choose whether output should be as a whole or not:

```
std::cout << std::left << std::setw(20) << foo().toString() << "!"; // output as expected
std::cout << foo();                                                 // output as expected 
                                                                    // and no unnecessary overhead
```

One might also argue that output is already slow, so a bit of additional overhead does not hurt and simply implement the output operator in terms of the stringify method:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const foo& f) {
    out << f.toString();
    return out;
}
```

This also fixed the minor ugliness of the first approach which basically implements the same thing twice with almost identical code.